# How to kill a request that took too long to execute in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to figure out how to kill a request that took more than 3 hours to execute.
Is it possible to do so?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `sp_who` to get a list of currently running sessions, or `SELECT @@SPID` to get the id of your current session. Once you know the SPID (Server Process ID), you can kill it with the `kill` command (so if you were SPID 57, you would type `kill 57`)

Answer (score 0):

Find the process in the `sys.sysprocesses` table.

Contact the person associated with the process (via some combination of the `hostname` and `loginame` columns), and have them take care of it.

If that's not an option, you can get the value of the `spid` and `kill` it.  For example, if the `spid` value is `12345`, just `kill 12345`.

Comment: From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysprocesses-transact-sql): `This SQL Server 2000 system table is included as a view for backward compatibility. We recommend that you use the current SQL Server system views instead.` I suggest using [sys.dm_exec_requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-requests-transact-sql) or, better yet, [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/).